# windows 7 difference between running ruby.exe vs ruby

Tags: ruby, windows

I have multiple versions of Ruby installed on my Windows 7 laptop.  I noticed that a different version of Ruby runs when I type `ruby hello.rb` vs `hello.rb`.  The first runs ruby 2.3, the second runs ruby 2.2.  I want to know why the two different ways of executing ruby runs two different versions.  I eventually want to delete ruby 2.2, but am concerned that running a ruby app without prefixing it with ruby will fail.

See code output

```
#!/bin/ruby
require 'tk';

where = `where ruby`;   where = "where ruby:\n" + where;
ver  = `ruby -v`;       ver  = ver[0..9];
path = ENV['PATH'];     path = path[0..52];

msg = 'Hello from Ruby ' + RUBY_VERSION + ' -OR- ' + ver;
print(where + "\n" + "PATH " + path + "\n" + msg + "\n");

root = TkRoot.new {title "Hello, World!"};
TkLabel.new(root) do text msg; pack {padx 15; pady 15; side 'left'}; end
Tk.mainloop;
```

Running `ruby hello.rb` yields expected results:

```
where ruby:
C:\Ruby23-x64\bin\ruby.exe
C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\ruby.exe

PATH C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;C:\ActiveTcl\bin;C:\Ruby24-x64\bin;
Hello from Ruby 2.3.3 -OR- ruby 2.3.3
```

Running `hello.rb` from prompt yields unexpected results. Note that `ruby2.2.6` is not even in `PATH`.

```
where ruby:
C:\Ruby23-x64\bin\ruby.exe
C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\ruby.exe

PATH C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;C:\ActiveTcl\bin;C:\Ruby24-x64\bin;
Hello from Ruby 2.2.6 -OR- ruby 2.3.3
```

Comment: In CMD, running `ruby` searches the current directory (can be disabled) and `PATH` for "ruby" plus the `PATHEXT` extensions. It should find ruby.exe and execute the command via WINAPI `CreateProcessW`. Running `hello.rb` searches for "hello.rb" plus the `PATHEXT` extensions (e.g. "hello.rb.EXE"). If found, it tries to execute the command via `CreateProcessW`. This fails since "hello.rb" isn't a PE executable, so CMD tries WINAPI `ShellExecuteExW`, which searches many keys in the registry to find the user's preferred template command for ".rb" files, e.g. `"C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\ruby.exe" "%1" %*`.

Comment: Thank you, eryksun.  I found the following in the registry: Application->ruby.exe->shell->open->cmd->Default.REG_SZ."C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\ruby.exe" "%1".  That explains my mystery.  I have never made a change to the registry before, but changing that value of Ruby22 to a different version should be a safe change.

Comment: `Applications\ruby.exe` (defined under "Classes, i.e. "[HKCU|HKLM]\Software\Classes") can be used as a ProgId for the user's ".rb" file association that's defined under "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts". Other associations may also be defined  by a ".rb" key under "Classes", which can reference a single ProgId as a default value, or multiple in an "OpenWithProgIds" subkey. A ProgId may be defined under "Classes", e.g. something like "RubyFile", with a shell "open" command. Another location for default ".rb" associations is "SystemFileAssociations" in "Classes".

Comment: There's even more registry spaghetti that can be involved with determining a file association. The Windows shell has accumulated a lot of cruft over the years.